# Segmentation Fault when operating on retrieved vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm kinda new to C++, and I have a question that I am curious about. For a while I was getting segmentation faults, though I did eventually make it work, but I would like to know why it wasn't before. This is what I had:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class A {
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        A(int i){this->num=i;}
        int getNum(){return this->num;}
};
class B {
    private:
        vector<A*> list;
    public:
        vector<A*> getList(){return this->list;}
        void addA(A* i){this->getList().push_back(i);}
        string as_a_string(){
            stringstream result;
            cout << "Flag1" <<endl; //only for debug, this prints
            for (vector<A*>::iterator x = this->getList().begin(); x != this->getList().end(); ++x) {
                cout << "Flag2" << endl; //only for debug, this prints
                A* w = *x;
                cout << "Flag3" << endl; //only for debug, this prints
                result << w->getNum() << " ";
                cout << "Flag4" << endl; //only for debug, this does not print
            }
            return result.str();
        }
};
int main() {
    A* a = new A(4);
    B* b = new B();
    b->addA(a);
    cout << b->as_a_string() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I solved my problem by replacing every instance of `this->getList()` with `this->list` (there were 3; one in `B::addA(A*)` and two in the for loop definition in `B::as_a_string()`). Why would using the member itself instead of accessing it through a method affect the workings of this program?

Comment: `getList()` is returning by value. Everytime you call it you're getting a copy of `B::list`.

Comment: I had thought of that, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to return a reference (I think that's the correct terminology, anyway) which would get it to behave the way I was thinking it should behave. How would I go about doing that properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `B::getList()` returns list by value and so a copy of `B::list` is actually returned rather than the original list itself.

In your loop here:

```
for (vector<A*>::iterator x = this->getList().begin();
     x != this->getList().end(); ++x)
```

You start by getting a begin iterator to this *temporary list*. Everytime the condition is checked, you are comparing it to the end iterator to a *different temporary* list object.

The easy fix for this is to have `B::getList()` return the list by reference:

```
vector<A*>& getList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `getList` is returning a temporary copy of `list`, the `list` is gone again when you try to iterate through it.

There are a few different ways to deal with this:

1. Just use `list` (no need to use `this->` - it is not PHP, Python or some such language where you always have to refer to members via the `this`/`self` pointer).
2. Let `getList` return a reference to the vector. (`vector<A*>& getList() { ... };`)
3. Use a local variable as a copy

However, option 3, that won't help in `addA`, which requires that you operati on the ORIGINAL list - as it stands, your `push_back` operate on a temporary copy of `list`, which is immediately destroyed after`push_back` returns - so it doesn't actually add anything at all to the actual `list` member variable).

Personally, I would change your internal code to use `list` directly, and keep `getList` returning a copy, so that if some external function wants to get hold of the list, it can.

Edit: You are also leaking memory by not deleing the A* and B* objects that you create in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
class B {
    private:
        vector<A*> list;
    public:
        vector<A*> getList(){return this->list;}
        void addA(A* i){this->getList().push_back(i);}
```

is calling push_back() on a temporary because getList() returns by value.  After calling add(), the member variable list is unchanged.  You can change your getList() function signature to return a reference like this:

```
vector<A*>& getList(){return this->list;}
```

Honestly, you probably are better off with the solution that you used to avoid the problem because providing a public accessor that returns a reference to your implementation details is something you would generally want to avoid.